# using innerHTML with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, innerhtml, userscripts

I am writing an userscript (for greasemonkey/firefox) to be used in a webpage.
It contains a series of  tag with a *onmouseover* attribute that do the following:

```
<area class="linkPoly" shape="poly" coords="450,175,412.5,200,450,225,487.5,200" href="home.php?msg=hello" onmouseover="showinfo('hello<br> world');">
```

the *showinfo()* function simply puts the html text passed by argument in a  accessible by ID.

What I am trying to do is scan the webpage for all the possible arguments of this function and  perform some operations.

The point is that I would like to access the *String* passed to *showinfo()* as an HTML object in order to avoid parsing the entire string.

I have tried doing the following:

```
var content="the html I have taken from showinfo"
var el = $( '<div></div>' );
el.html(content);
GM_log(el.innerHTML);
```

but I get an *Undefined* error in the console.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The el is jQuery object and you are trying to use innerHTML on it. Convert jQuery object to DOM object to use innerHTML property as it is not available with jQuery object.

```
GM_log(el[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Ok I have corrected it and now I can correctly access either el.html() and el[0].innerHTML.